# trace single characters in a string in R

Tags: regex, string, r

I want to search for single characters in a string and concatenate them with the next word in the string

Ex:

```
INPUT :  "B 123, G BLOCK SUN SHINE APPTS"
OUTPUT : "B123, GBLOCK SUN SHINE APPTS"
```

I had tried to extract the single character elements out of the string first using str_extract, but found that it results only the first occurrence of the pattern.

```
> str_extract("B 123, G BLOCK SUN SHINE APPTS", "[a-zA-Z]{1}")
[1] "B"
```

Any help on this would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example you can do this :

```
## extracts words
xx <- unlist(strsplit('B 123, G BLOCK SUN SHINE APPTS'," "))
## get one letter words
idx <- which(nchar(xx)==1) 
## concatenate them with the next words then replace them in the origin
xx[idx+1] <- paste0(xx[idx] ,xx[idx + 1 ])
## remove them one letter words and join all words 
paste(xx[-idx],collapse=' ')

[1] "B123, GBLOCK SUN SHINE APPTS"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`gsub`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) to do this.

```
x <- 'B 123, G BLOCK SUN SHINE APPTS'
gsub('(?<=\\b[a-zA-Z]\\b)\\s+', '', x, perl=T)

[1] "B123, GBLOCK SUN SHINE APPTS"
```